# no such table in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new in android development and I had built one app for login and it runs successfully..but when I create another table in database and it gives me error that `no such table:customizeformdetails  and     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: customizeformdetails (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO customizeformdetails(JSON) VALUES (?)`

My Code is :LoginDatabseAdapter

```
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
// TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
// SQL Statement to create a new database.
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+"adminreg"+
        "( " +"AdminRegID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "Rest_name text,Contact_person_name text,Designation text,Contact_no text,Email_addr text,PASSWORD text,Address text); ";
// Variable to hold the database instance

static final String DATABASE_FEEDBACKFORM="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+"customizeformdetails"+
       "("+"CustomizeFormId"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+"JSON text);";

public SQLiteDatabase db;
// Context of the application using the database.
private final Context context;
// Database open/upgrade helper
private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
public  LoginDatabaseAdapter(Context _context)
{
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
public  LoginDatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close()
{
    db.close();
}

public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
{
    return db;
}

public void insertEntry(String Rest_name,String Contact_person_name,String Designation,String Contact_no,String Email_addr,String PASSWORD, String Address)
{
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put("Rest_name", Rest_name);
    newValues.put("Contact_person_name",Contact_person_name);
    newValues.put("Designation",Designation);
    newValues.put("Contact_no",Contact_no);
    newValues.put("Email_addr",Email_addr);
    newValues.put("PASSWORD",PASSWORD);
    newValues.put("Address",Address);

    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("adminreg", null, newValues);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("context", "Toast");
}

public void insertCustomizeEntry(String json)
{
    Log.e("Data Insert reached","yes");
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put("JSON",json);
    db.insert("customizeformdetails", null, newValues);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Data Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("context", "Toast");
    selectCustomizeEntry();

}

public String selectCustomizeEntry()
{
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM customizeformdetails", null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String customizeFormDetails= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("JSON"));
    Log.e("Data",customizeFormDetails);
    return  customizeFormDetails;

}
```

DatabseHelper.cs :

```
 public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
{
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}
// Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
// to create a new one.
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db)
{
    _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LoginDatabaseAdapter.DATABASE_FEEDBACKFORM);
   _db.execSQL(LoginDatabaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);
    _db.execSQL(LoginDatabaseAdapter.DATABASE_FEEDBACKFORM);

}
```

Please help me..It already taken so much time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CREATE TABLE SQL Command` is wrong.

```
static final String DATABASE_FEEDBACKFORM="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+" customizeformdetails "+
   "("+"CustomizeFormId"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+" JSON text);";
```

Add space after `Column Name` and `Column Type` also add space between `EXISTS` and the table name.

Comment: ERROR in databsehelper class: Non static field DATABASE_FEEDBACKFORM cannot be a static context

Comment: I had just write this but still getting error :No such table customizeform--   static final String DATABASE_FEEDBACKFORM="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+" customizeform "+
            "("+"CustomizeId"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+" JSON text,AdminId text,JSON_modified text);";

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax problems in your `CREATE TABLE` SQL: for example, whitespace missing between `EXISTS` and the table name. Since you didn't mention any exception being thrown, the SQL in your `onCreate()` was not executed. The reason for that is that the database file already existed.

1. Fix the syntax problems.
2. Uninstall your app so that the old database file gets removed and `onCreate()` will be invoked again.

Comment: I had just write this but still getting error :No such table customizeform--   static final String DATABASE_FEEDBACKFORM="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+" customizeform "+
            "("+"CustomizeId"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+" JSON text,AdminId text,JSON_modified text);";